# Represent nested resources that has two different type (entites) owners in REST APIs?

Tags: rest, api, json

Suppose I have a entity called `Appointment`. This entity represents an medical appointment between one `Doctor` and one `Patient`.

To create a new `Appointment`, I send somethind like:

`POST /appointments`

```
{
  "doctorId": 98173821,
  "patientId": 2138212,
  ... omitted for brevity
}
```

Works well.

As you can see, this object is nested with two other resources (`Patient` and `Doctor`)

Imagine that logged `Patient` (using his JWT Token) want to see his history of `Appointments`.

Today, I do that sending a request to:

`GET /patients/2138212/appointments?page=1&size=2&startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-08-01`

*(please, feel free to criticize)*

as this is a history, there's no need to retrieve the whole `Appointment` objects. The response retrieves only basic informations about the `Appointments`. The response looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1566216359,
  "transactionId": "6eed92831cad128",
  "data": {
    "appointments": [
      {
        "id": 6372,
        "doctorId": 98173821,
        "date": "2019-01-01"
      },
      {
        "id": 6985,
        "doctorId": 98173821,
        "date": "2019-02-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, what if the `Patient` select an specific `Appointment` in the front-end and the detailed information about this specific `Appointment` needs to be shown? What is the best way to model a REST endpoint like this?

My options:

- `GET /patients/2138212/appointments/6372`
- `GET /appointments/6372`

The first one looks nice and follow up REST patterns on nested resources, since can represent that the `Appointment` 6372 belongs to the `Patient` 2138212.

The second one doesn't provide readability. I mean, looking at the resource, I don't know who owns this `Appointment`. That's why I prefer the first approach.

Now, going down the road, also, the `Doctor` has to see the history of his Appointments.

Today, I do that sending a request to:

`GET /doctors/98173821/appointments?page=1&size=2&startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-08-01`

*(please, feel free to criticize)*

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1566216359,
  "transactionId": "6eed92831cad321",
  "data": {
    "appointments": [
      {
        "id": 6372,
        "patientId": 2138212,
        "date": "2019-01-01"
      },
      {
        "id": 6985,
        "patientId": 2138212,
        "date": "2019-02-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, what if the `Doctor` select an specific `Appointment` in the front-end and the detailed information about this specific `Appointment` needs to be shown? What is the best way to model a REST endpoint like this?

My options:

- `GET /doctors/98173821/appointments/6372`
- `GET /appointments/6372`

The questions I have:

1. How to represent a nested resource that has "two owners"? There is a better approach than this I point out on that question?
2. To the history of `Appointments`, I've been suggested to do `/appointments/doctors/{doctorId}` and `/appointments/patients/{patientId}`, which I heavily disagree, since the `Doctor` and the `Patient` **owns** the `Appointment`, **not the opposite**. What you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You can have

- GET /appointments/6372

as canonical url for appointment 6372

and two non canonical urls:

- GET /patients/2138212/appointments/6372
- GET /doctors/98173821/appointments/6372

non cannonical urls would add Link header with rel="cannonical" link to canonical url